# Get MAXvalue from column where comparing to other columns?

Tags: aggregate-functions, azure-data-factory

Input table:

| Type | Comment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | value2 | 20 |
| A | value5 | 19 |
| B | value8 | 20 |
| A | value2 | 17 |
| A | value5 | 20 |
| B | value8 | 20 |
| C | value2 | 21 |
| A | value5 | 23 |
| B | value8 | 23 |

Final Table:

| Type | Comment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | value5 | 23 |
| B | value8 | 23 |
| C | value2 | 21 |

Comment: Hey, what is the source of this table?
You can leverage partition function and create a select query as source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nandan says, you can create a select query as source.

Another way, you can use Aggregate transformation to do this.

Steps:

1.After adding your source, add a Aggregate transformation. It's setting as the following screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Data Preview:

[image]

2. New a branch of your source, then join your branch and Aggregate transformation.

[image]

3. Add a Select transformation to delete the duplicate columns.

[image]

4. Result:

[image]

Comment: It's so helpful!!!